# A small doubt in Kähler geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, kahler-manifolds

We often use this lemma in Kähler geometry. For a compact Kähler manifold $(X,\omega)$ and a function $f$ on $X$ we have
\begin{align*}
\langle\partial\bar\partial f,\omega\rangle=\frac{i}{2}\Delta(f)
\end{align*}
But I am thinking
\begin{align*}
\langle\partial\bar\partial f,\omega\rangle=\langle\bar\partial f,\partial^*\omega\rangle=\langle\bar\partial f,0\rangle=0
\end{align*}
I must be making some big mistake here. Any help?

Comment: They are only taking pointwise inner product on $\Omega^{1,1}_xX$, not the global one.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification.